# How do I comment on the Gibbs energy values standard and reaction in different situations?

Tags: physical-chemistry, equilibrium

I have the following graphs:

[image]

[image]

Taking into account the following graphs, how do I comment on the Gibbs energy values
standard and Gibbs energy of reaction in different situations (a, b and c), and how do I relate the values of the latter to the spontaneity of the reaction? I'm really lost here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph is a little bit confused, because there exist different sorts of Gibbs energy. i
It can be the Gibbs energy of the rectant. It can be the Gibbs energy of the products. And it can also be the total of these two Gibbs energies.

First let's discuss the Gibbs energy of the reactant. In the beginning of the reaction, the Gibbs energy of the reactant is high. But when the reactants are consumed, their Gibbs energy decrease, because Gibbs energy is not like enthalpy which does not change if the concentration changes. No ! Gibbs energy of a substance decreases at low concentrations. So the curve of the Gibbs energy of the reactant decreases all the time, during the reaction. The value of the final point is not important.

Now let's discuss about the Gibbs energy of the product. At the beginning of the reaction, there is practically no product yet. The Gibbs energy of the product is very low. As the reaction goes ahead, the amount of the product increases. So the curve of its Gibbs energy increases. The final point of this increasing curve is rather important. It may be higher or lower the initial value of the Gibbs energy of the reactant. If it is lower, it means that the reaction Reactant - Products is spontaneous. If it is higher, It means that the reaction Reactant - Product is not spontaneous.

But what is most important is the sum of these two curves. Because the sum of the Gibbs energies of reactants + the Gibbs energy of the product, well , this sum has a minimum somewhere. And the position of the minimum gives the values of the equilibrium constant of the reaction. It is $b$ on your picture.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a labeled and annotated version of your graph (from [OpenStax Chemistry](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/General_Chemistry/Chemistry_(OpenSTAX)/16%3A_Thermodynamics/16.4%3A_Gibbs_Energy)).

[image]